# Keystonejs : Error in updating user's profile; name, email, pass and etc

Tags: node.js, express, content-management-system, dashboard, keystonejs

I'm new to keystone js. Right now I'm making a web app that has user dashboard. I'm trying to use the method of updateItem upon a user item, which already been indexed / searched / queried in the first parameter of the function.

```
// KEYSTONE METHOD
User.updateItem({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {
    fields: 'user',
    flashErrors: true,
    logErrors: true},
function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("An error happened!");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        return res.redirect('/dashboard/' + req.params.id);
    }
    next();
});
```

Error popped up in console, shows:

```
{
 error: 'invalid configuration',
 detail: 'Invalid path specified in fields to update [user] for list User'
}
```

It seems that it doesn't found the user model. I wanted to console.log if the system found the user model through callbacks params, but this method doesn't have one.

As I said, I'm really new in keystonejs and I'm not even close to understanding it fully of how things really work here.
But, I feel like it's really close to work...

** CODE REF : Dashboard views **

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var user     = keystone.list("User");
var User     = keystone.List("User");

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {
var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
var locals = res.locals;

// Init locals
locals.currentUser = req.body || {};

view.query('currentUser', user.model.findById(req.params.id));

view.on('post', { action: 'user.update' }, function(next) {

    // KEYSTONE METHOD
    User.updateItem({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {
        fields: 'user',
        flashErrors: true,
        logErrors: true},
    function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("An error happened!");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            return res.redirect('/dashboard/' + req.params.id);
        }
        next();
    });
});

// Render the view
view.render('../dashboard/dashboard-main');
```

};

** CODE REF : Jade code **

```
form(method="post")
    input(type='hidden', name='action',  value='user.update')

        .row.mb-4
            .col-md-4
                label First Name
                input.form-control(type="text" name="first" value=currentUser.name.first)

            .col-md-4
                label Last Name
                input.form-control(type="text" name="last" value=currentUser.name.last)

            .row.mb-10
                .col-md-12
                    button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit")
                        i.fa.fa-fw.fa-lg.fa-check-circle
                        |  Save
```

Here's the User model:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

/**
 * User Model
 * ==========
 */
var User = new keystone.List('User');

User.add({
    name: { type: Types.Name, required: true, index: true },
    email: { type: Types.Email, initial: true, required: true, unique: true, index: true },
    password: { type: Types.Password, initial: true, required: true },
}, 'Permissions', {
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, label: 'Can access Keystone', index: true },
});

// Provide access to Keystone
User.schema.virtual('canAccessKeystone').get(function () {
    return this.isAdmin;
});


/**
 * Relationships
 */
User.relationship({ ref: 'Post', path: 'posts', refPath: 'author' });


/**
 * Registration
 */
User.defaultColumns = 'name, email, isAdmin';
User.register();
```

Note: I've used yeoman generator for this app, and just added new route file, and jade view file for the user dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

```
var User = keystone.List("User");
```

is invalid in your view / route.js. You only use the capitalized .List when you are creating a new List in your model, as it is a class initiation, like you have in your model.

Therefore the correct context for your dashboard view is likely to be:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var user     = keystone.list("User");
/* var User     = keystone.List("User"); */

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {
var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
var locals = res.locals;

// Init locals
locals.currentUser = req.body || {};

view.query('currentUser', user.model.findById(req.params.id));

view.on('post', { action: 'user.update' }, function(next) {

    // KEYSTONE 
    /* User.updateItem({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, { */
    user.updateItem({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {
        fields: 'user',
        flashErrors: true,
        logErrors: true},
    function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("An error happened!");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            return res.redirect('/dashboard/' + req.params.id);
        }
        next();
    });
});

// Render the view
view.render('../dashboard/dashboard-main');
```

Comment: var user     = keystone.list("User");
var User     = keystone.List("User");

These lines, I experimented it around, and it's very different, I console.log, used their functions, and they're different, the un-capitalized seem to function more to accessing mongoose methods, while the capitalized one seem to function more to model methods, and the their docs is so unhelpful in this situation, everything is so confusing.
The querying works fine, as I could send the locals currentUser (variables) to pug file. The updateItem method also works, but it seems not syncing with User.js model file....

Comment: Forgot your advice to use User.model.updateItem. Tried it, both User.model.updateItem and user.model.updateItem doesn't work...

Comment: Used your advice, another prob popped up. An error happened!
{ error: 'invalid configuration',
  detail: 'Invalid path specified in fields to update [user] for list User' }. Edited the fields in updateItem; **fields : 'user'** => **fields : 'name'**. It then shows TypeError: item.get is not a function, and then crashed the app. Sorry as this is very tedious...

Comment: Btw, if you have another way / **your way** of editing updating **user**'s information, including passwords using keystone's methods, I would really appreciate it... Thanks

Comment: Basic user fields; name, email, password, and other, lot more user fields; websites, twitter link, fb link, and more to come. Have no problem with others (mongoose C.R.U.D.s), but only with using keystone on setting the very basic, furthermore setting the password. I have no experience before this with keystone at all fyi... Or should I use **updateHandler()** ?